# Многократное распараллеливание коротких вычислений

Tags: java, распараллеливание

Задача: необходимо распараллеливать вычисление нескольких моделей N времени (N последовательных итераций). Модель за 1 раз выполняет короткое вычисление численным методом (Эйлером / Рунге-Куттом или др. методом). Количество моделей N, после итерации вычисления N моделей происходит обмен результатами вычислений, состояние модели меняется и влияет таким образом на результат вычислений на следующей итерации, последовательность вычисления итераций важна (модель показывает как будет будет меняться ее состояние во времени при условии численного интегрирования маленькими временными шагами). Далее пример от балды, т.к. в реальности сложнее:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  model1.calculate();
  model2.calculate();

  model2.setU(model1.getU());
  model1.setI(model2.getI());
}
```

Количество итераций может быть большим, при этом нужно успеть моделировать до 100 000 итераций в реальную секунду. Распараллеливать можно только в пределах текущей итерации, т.е. model1.calculate() и model2.calculate().
Пока что не удалось написать эффективное распараллеливание - последовательно работает быстрее.

Вот мои попытки написать распараллеливание:

```
package jcscore;

public class Model {
    private static final int SYSTEM_EQUATION_LENGTH = 200;
    private static final int LAST_INDEX = SYSTEM_EQUATION_LENGTH - 1;
    private static final int INPUT_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int OUTPUT_INDEX = 5;
    private final double[] factors = new double[SYSTEM_EQUATION_LENGTH];
    private final double[] state = new double[SYSTEM_EQUATION_LENGTH];

    public Model(double factorInit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
            factors[i] = i * i * factorInit;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
            state[i] = i * i * 123.0;
        }
    }

    public void calculate(double timeStep) {
        state[0] = state[LAST_INDEX] + state[0] * factors[0] * timeStep;

        for (int i = LAST_INDEX; i > 0; i--) {
            // dstate / timeStep = state[i-1] * factor
            state[i] = state[i] + state[i - 1] * factors[i] * timeStep;
        }
    }

    public void setInput(double value) {
        state[INPUT_INDEX] = value;
    }

    public double getOutput() {
        return state[OUTPUT_INDEX];
    }
}
```

```
package jcscore;

public class ModelExchanger {
    private final Model[] models;
    private final int length;
    private final int lastIndex;

    public ModelExchanger(Model... models) {
        this.models = models;
        this.length = models.length;
        lastIndex = length - 1;
    }

    public void exchange() {
        models[0].setInput(models[lastIndex].getOutput());
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            models[i].setInput(models[lastIndex].getOutput());
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class BenchmarkMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

```
package jcscore;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Threads;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ModelParallelizationTest
{
        @Benchmark
        @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
        public void testNotParallelization() {
                final double timeStep = 0.000001;
                ActionRunnable task1 = new ActionRunnable(0.0001, timeStep);
                ActionRunnable task2 = new ActionRunnable(0.0002, timeStep);
                ActionRunnable task3 = new ActionRunnable(0.0003, timeStep);
                ModelExchanger modelExchanger = new ModelExchanger(task1.getModel(), task2.getModel(), task3.getModel());

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                        task1.run();
                        task2.run();
                        task3.run();

                        task1.clear();
                        task2.clear();
                        task3.clear();
                        modelExchanger.exchange();
                }

                Assert.assertEquals(3075.0049, task1.getModel().getOutput(), 0.001);
        }

        @Threads(5)
        @Benchmark
        @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
        public void testServiceExecutor() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
                final double timeStep = 0.000001;
                ActionRunnable task1 = new ActionRunnable(0.0001, timeStep);
                ActionRunnable task2 = new ActionRunnable(0.0002, timeStep);
                ActionRunnable task3 = new ActionRunnable(0.0003, timeStep);
                ModelExchanger modelExchanger = new ModelExchanger(task1.getModel(), task2.getModel(), task3.getModel());

                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                        Future future1 = executor.submit(task1);
                        Future future2 = executor.submit(task2);
                        Future future3 = executor.submit(task3);

                        future1.get();
                        future2.get();
                        future3.get();

                        task1.clear();
                        task2.clear();
                        task3.clear();
                        modelExchanger.exchange();
                }

                executor.shutdown();

                Assert.assertEquals(3075.0049, task1.getModel().getOutput(), 0.001);
        }

        @Threads(5)
        @Benchmark
        @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
        public void testForkJoin() {
                final double timeStep = 0.000001;
                ForkJoinAction task1 = new ForkJoinAction(0.0001, timeStep);
                ForkJoinAction task2 = new ForkJoinAction(0.0002, timeStep);
                ForkJoinAction task3 = new ForkJoinAction(0.0003, timeStep);
                ForkJoinAction[] tasks = {task1, task2, task3};
                ModelExchanger modelExchanger = new ModelExchanger(task1.getModel(), task2.getModel(), task3.getModel());

                ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
                ForkJoinActions forkJoinActions = new ForkJoinActions(tasks);

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                        forkJoinPool.invoke(forkJoinActions);

                        task1.clear();
                        task2.clear();
                        task3.clear();
                        modelExchanger.exchange();
                }

                Assert.assertEquals(3075.0000049, task1.getModel().getOutput(), 0.001);
        }

        @Threads(5)
        @Benchmark
        @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
        public void testStreamParallel()
        {
                final double timeStep = 0.000001;
                ActionRunnable task1 = new ActionRunnable(0.0001, timeStep);
                ActionRunnable task2 = new ActionRunnable(0.0002, timeStep);
                ActionRunnable task3 = new ActionRunnable(0.0003, timeStep);
                ModelExchanger modelExchanger = new ModelExchanger(task1.getModel(), task2.getModel(), task3.getModel());

                List<ActionRunnable> tasks = Arrays.asList(task1, task2, task3);
                Consumer<ActionRunnable> taskConsumer = ActionRunnable::run;

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                        tasks.parallelStream().forEach(taskConsumer);

                        task1.clear();
                        task2.clear();
                        task3.clear();
                        modelExchanger.exchange();
                }

                Assert.assertEquals(3075.0049, task1.getModel().getOutput(), 0.001);
        }

        @Getter
        public static class ActionRunnable implements Runnable
        {
                private final Model model;
                private double timeStep;
                private boolean complete = false;

                public ActionRunnable(double factorInit, double timeStep)
                {
                        this.model = new Model(factorInit);
                        this.timeStep = timeStep;
                }

                public Model getModel() {
                        return model;
                }

                public void clear()
                {
                        complete = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                        model.calculate(timeStep);
                        complete = true;
                }
        }

        @Getter
        public static class ForkJoinAction extends RecursiveTask<Void>
        {
                private final Model model;
                private double timeStep;
                private boolean complete = false;

                public ForkJoinAction(double factorInit, double timeStep)
                {
                        this.model = new Model(factorInit);
                        this.timeStep = timeStep;
                }

                public Model getModel() {
                        return model;
                }

                public void clear()
                {
                        complete = false;
                }

                @Override
                public Void compute()
                {
                        model.calculate(timeStep);
                        complete = true;
                        return null;
                }
        }

        public static class ForkJoinActions extends RecursiveTask<Void>
        {
                private final ForkJoinAction[] actions;

                public ForkJoinActions(ForkJoinAction[] actions)
                {
                        this.actions = actions;
                }

                @Override
                protected Void compute()
                {
                        final int length = actions.length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                        {
                                actions[i].fork(); // запустим асинхронно
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                        {
                                actions[i].join(); // дождёмся выполнения задачи
                        }
                        return null;
                }
        }
}
```

Результаты:

```
Result "jcscore.ModelParallelizationTest.testNotParallelization":
  0,001 ±(99.9%) 0,001 s/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (≈ 10⁻³, 0,001, 0,001), stdev = 0,001
  CI (99.9%): [≈ 10⁻³, 0,001] (assumes normal distribution)

Result "jcscore.ModelParallelizationTest.testServiceExecutor":
  0,015 ±(99.9%) 0,001 s/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (0,012, 0,015, 0,019), stdev = 0,002
  CI (99.9%): [0,014, 0,017] (assumes normal distribution)
  
Result "jcscore.ModelParallelizationTest.testForkJoin":
  0,061 ±(99.9%) 0,016 s/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (0,027, 0,061, 0,103), stdev = 0,022
  CI (99.9%): [0,044, 0,077] (assumes normal distribution)
  
Result "jcscore.ModelParallelizationTest.testStreamParallel":
  0,002 ±(99.9%) 0,001 s/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (0,002, 0,002, 0,003), stdev = 0,001
  CI (99.9%): [0,002, 0,002] (assumes normal distribution)

Benchmark                                           Mode  Cnt  Score    Error  Units
ModelParallelizationTest.testNotParallelization  avgt   25  0,001 ±  0,001   s/op
ModelParallelizationTest.testServiceExecutor  avgt   25  0,015 ± 0,001   s/op
ModelParallelizationTest.testForkJoin  avgt   25  0,061 ± 0,016   s/op
ModelParallelizationTest.testStreamParallel  avgt   25  0,002 ±  0,001   s/op
```

Необходимо, чтобы распараллеливание давало значительное преимущество над последовательным вычислением. Есть идеи как ускорить распараллеливание?

Comment: а зачем в testServiceExecutor создавать и вырубать newFixedThreadPool на каждой итерации? Вынесите из цикла, а в самом цикле получайте Future'ы из submit и используй get, чтобы подождать пока посчитает. Хотя всё навряд ли распараллеленная версия покажет лучшие результаты на таких маленьких тестах

Comment: IR42 спасибо за совет, поправил код теста. Стало лучше чем было, но задачу пока не решило, еще заметил что увеличение цикла в задаче теперь не улучшает распараллеливание.
В идеале внутри цикла нужно обойтись без создания новых объектов.

Comment: При более долгих операциях результаты противоречивей.

Comment: забыл добавить, что executor.shutdown(); не ожидает завершения задач, поэтому ваш вариант, где вы на каждой итерации создаёте трейдпул и вызываете executor.shutdown(); некорректен. И странные у вас результаты, у меня в jmh последовательный тест быстрее в 3 раза распараллеленного, а если увеличить цикл в 100 раз, то последовательный уже начинает проигрывать параллельному в ~2.5 раза

Comment: измерил длительность выполнения своих моделей и приблизил тесты к реальной задаче. имеем ухудшение распараллеливания в 15раз.

Comment: Попробовал на CyclicBarrier написать свою реализацию - реализация оказалась в 20раз медленней последовательной.

Comment: *Общие (безотносительно Java) соображения о параллельных вычислениях*. Современные компьютеры устроены так, что параллельный код работает быстро, если он в процессе вычислений не взаимодействует с другими потоками. Например, у вас есть большой (скажем, гигабйтный) массив и каждый из N потоков (желательно чтобы N равнялось количеству реальных CPU) обрабатывает свою часть массива, создавая свой массив результатов. И  только после окончания работы эти потоки сообщают, что обработка завершена. Попробуйте перестроить свою задачу в духе описанной модели вычислений.

Answer (score -2):

лутшее решение использовать parallelStream()

или же если вы знакомы с концепцией форкджоин пула, что по сути одно и тоже

Comment: добавил тест со стримом и результаты, так имели в виду?

А с ForkJoin совсем плохо вышло (нагрузка на память и GC - из-за этого результаты сильно колеблются)